# How to identify if a process is java or c or c++ process in linux?

Tags: java, c++, c

`ps -eaf | grep java` command is not a solution here to identify if a process is a java process or not, as many of my java processes are not listed in the output after executing this command.

Comment: `jps` usually works

Comment: Then how are they listed in the `ps` output? Of course, you may have the problem that a process is *both* C++ *and* Java.

Comment: will `pstree` help?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer (hopefully someone writes a more comprehensive one):

1. Get process PID
2. Go to `/proc/<pid>`
3. Look up the process binary file from there
4. Run commands `file` and `ldd` on it and see what you can figure out from their output (check man pages of the commands, of course).
5. Use `lsof` command to see which files the process has open, and see if those include telltale libraries or similar files.

Answer (score 0):

This thread explains how to find which process a jvm is running

https://superuser.com/questions/441792/how-do-i-determine-what-running-process-is-using-java

So you might just check through all the virtual machines and check if they are running the process ID you're looking for. If not, it must be some other language.

Answer (score 0):

Jab process must be executed by a Java executable. So to view that process you must see the command line that is being running. 
Ps -ef
Or 
Jps
Or 
Htop

Are common solutions